# Webgl build fps decrease over time (Chrome)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

We are working on optimizing our webgl build (intended to be run on chromebooks, chrome latest version). 
Currently we have achieved about ~40 fps throughout the game which is quite near our requirement.

The issue is that if the game is left "on" for some time (e.g 30-45 minutes), the fps gradually drop from the initial 40 fps to about 20 fps and then continue to decrease in the same manner if game is left on.

We can say this isnt due to gpu because in all our scenes the draw calls are about 100-150 and they stay constant. Furthermore we have optimized as far as gpu is considered (static/dynamic batching, gpu instancing, disabled shadows, texture compression etc).

Currently we are unable to profile the actual build (since the development build is about 2gb which cant be loaded in any browser), hence we are profiling the editor.

Deep profiling the cpu scripts doesnt reveal anything obvious that could be gradually eating up the fps over a period of 45 minutes.

Has anyone else encountered this in their WebGl builds?
Any advice for optimization and maintaining a consistent fps?

Thanks.

Comment: My advice would be to make a spinning cube and leave it running for 48hrs. if it slows down file a bug with Unity. If it doesn't try 100 cubes. If that fails file a bug. If not start bisecting. Remove 50% of your code and see if it repos. Repeat until you narrow down the code or feature that is causing the issue.

Comment: @mjwills I'll try to create minimal reproducible example and share.

Comment: @gman Thanks I'll give that a try and report the findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity's audio source was causing the fps drop in the Webgl build. We replaced it with this [asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/streaming-audio-source-for-unity-webgl-75612) and the fps drop vanished.